# Glide not loading image or throwing error in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-glide

Glide is not loading my image synchronously inside my AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(EventAppSetupModel... params) {
     File icon = Glide.with(mContext).load("https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png").downloadOnly(512, 512).get();
```

The AsyncTask just hangs. I am not getting any logging, even with [the error logging enabled](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling). When i set a listener, none of the methods of the listeners are ever called. If i do set a timeout of 15 seconds, it times out without giving me any other information. This happens for any image for any server.

How can I load and resize an image into a file with Glide synchronously?

Comment: From where do you call glide?

Comment: And why do you want it synchronous?

Comment: It is unclear if glide does what you want outside an asynctask.

Comment: Inside the doInBackground of the asynctask. I want it synchronous because i want to wait for multiple images in this asynctask before moving on.

Comment: Please answer all my questions/comments.

Comment: Where would glide save the downloaded file?

Comment: you can't update UI in doInBackground.

Comment: Im not trying to update the UI from the background thread. The file would be saved in Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS). The app does have permission to access this directory.